# Is this kebab roll ingredient referring to the seed, outer star or both?

Tags: ingredient-selection

[image]

I am referring to star anise.  This is an ingredient list for store bought kebab rolls(I think they’re also referred to as sheek kebabs).  I’m under the impression that the seed and outer star if star anise have different flavour profiles.  When it mentions star anise I’m this list, would it be referring to the ground seed, ground outer star or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This likely refers to the ground spice, and probably the whole thing.  Spices used on an industrial scale are usually sourced economically.  In other words, the most inexpensive ground star anise.  It is likely that this is the whole thing ground up.